# Count up from date and display weeks and days only - PHP

Tags: php

How can you count up from a date, May 7, 2016 and just display the number of weeks and days (5 Weeks 1 Day) from that date with the least amount of code?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<?php
$date = "May 07, 2011";
$date = strtotime($date);

$week=5;
$day=1;
$days=(5*7)+1;
$date = strtotime("+".$days." day", $date);
echo date('M d, Y', $date);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP DateTime class.

```
$lastDate="2016-10-10";
$date1 = new DateTime("2016-05-07");
$date2 = new DateTime($lastDate);
$difference = $date1->diff($date2);

echo "difference " .floor($difference->days/7)." weeks, ".($interval->days%7)." days ";
```

Get the number of weeks by dividing and modulus by 7 as above